# Is there any editor out there that supports code hinting for LESS files?

Tags: less, code-editor

Is there any editor out there that supports code hinting for LESS files?

Comment: Hinting or syntax highlighting? For quicker typing, [Zen CSS](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) works fine with LESS.

Comment: I think my new answer is more helpful than the one I gave a few months ago, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

[WebStorm editor](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm) offers their own code analysis tool (hinter?) with support for LESS included among all the other file types that they support, WebStorm is awesome and it is payware rightly so.

If you need a free tool, you can use [twitter's recess](http://twitter.github.io/recess/) and [Sublime Text 2](https://www.sublimetext.com/2) [or 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) to lint your less formated css. You're gonna need to install [npm](https://www.npmjs.org) which comes bundled with [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) (and you might want to consider installing nodeJS using a version manager like [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) or [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) so you can seamlessly update and switch versions as needed).

Once you have npm installed and available from command line ("terminal" or tty):
Install recess globally.
`sudo npm install recess -g`
And then install the sublime plugin from [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then `install package` and search `twitter recess`

Answer (score 0):

Of course!

If you use **Sublime Text 2**, there is a plugin:

https://github.com/danro/LESS-sublime

Answer (score 0):

[WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) has LESS highlighting and IntelliSense-type hinting.